# Nested or non-nested anonymous namespace to hide implementation details

Tags: c++, namespaces

What's the difference between nesting anonymous namespace vs having it at top level in the translation unit?

```
namespace Named {
    namespace {
        void impl () {...}
   }

   void fun ()
   {
       impl();
   }
}
```

Or

```
namespace {
    void impl () {...}
}

namespace Named {
    void fun ()
    {
        impl();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Replace `impl();` with `::Named::impl();` or `::impl();` The first and second version will only work with the first and second of your code snippets respectively... Both code snippets in your question should have the same effect though as long as there are no other `impl` symbols in your translation unit...

Comment: There are differences in the name lookup inside the body of `impl` in both cases too of course. Note that there could be changes caused by ADL too, if you're adding parameters to the function. (ADL only works, if both the type of an argument and the function recide in the same namespace.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as with all namespaces - lookup rules. In  first example, if `Named` already has own `void impl(){}`, that would be an error. In the second, if `Named::impl` exists, it will be silently taken over `anonymous-namespace::impl`. [See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/MEz6Efxcn)

Comment: I guess my question is: which approach is preferable (just style-wise or for other reasons) when hiding implementation details?

Comment: @user2052436 First version seems better to me in any case - in case of duplicate definitions you get an error, it lets you refer to use names from `Named` in `impl` without explicit namespace and you can add operator overloads for types from `Named` in the anonymous namespace.